# Perl "-C" flag question

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, flags

Why doesn't the "-C" flag have an option to enable the "use utf8"-pragma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess it is because they control different aspects of encoding:

- The [-C](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) flag controls the default encoding of input and output streams *read or written* by the program.
- The [use utf8](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) pragma tells the Perl parser if the *source code* is UTF-8. This can also be detected by a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the source file.

Comment: Right, `-C` only controls how data is handled (stdin/out/err, arguments), not the source. If one really needs to use a command-line option to specify UTF-8 source, then `-Mutf8` should work.

Comment: OK, but for me as user a flag as a sort of front-end for Unicode/UTF-8 would be nice. So I could write shorter one-liner.

Comment: Most of what `-C` does can be taken care of by the `use io` pragma, except (to the best of my knowledge) for the `-CA` option.

Comment: @tchrist: I think you are thinking of the `open` pragma?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of `use open`.